# Albert Camus's quote from 'Resistance, Rebellion, and Death'

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

> “When the imagination sleeps, words are emptied of their meaning: a deaf population absent-mindedly registers the condemnation of a man.... there is no other solution but to speak out and show the obscenity hidden under the verbal cloak.”
>   ―Albert Camus

Could anyone explain what this quote means? Does it mean something along the lines of lost of creativity leading to people getting 'lost' in a sense that they do not know what to do?

Answer (score 4):

Camus is speaking against [death penalty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflections_on_the_Guillotine).

His critic is direct towards the use of language made by authorities and journalists to hide the cruelty of death penalty, with locutions like ([see page 176](https://books.google.it/books?id=agDnZvSJ5r8C&pg=PA176)):

> "debt to society", "to do justice", "the interested party".

In this context, the reference to *lack of imagination* must be understootd as a way to explain the fact that people fail to "see" the cruelty because they do not attend at the execution and thus the "expurgated" language hides the horror of the execution ([see page 177](https://books.google.it/books?id=agDnZvSJ5r8C&pg=PA177)):

> if people are shown the machine [the guillotine], made to touch the wood and steel and to hear the sound of a head falling, then *public imagination* [meaning: the public sentiment/opinion], suddenly awakened, will repudiate both the vocabulary and the penalty.

See also [Camus and the death penalty](http://www.iep.utm.edu/camus/#SSH5cviii).

Comment: 'When the imagination sleeps, words are emptied of their meaning'. What does imagination mean in this context ? and Thanks for answering!

Comment: @NgTzeKean - as you can see, the essay has nothing to do with "philosophy of mind".

Answer (score 0):

Imagination here includes affect; cold calculation asserts an obscenity the calculator is sympathetically infatuated by as meaning-a new death excites death’s partisans. Sand absorbs blood, the coliseum empties via paved exits.

Answer (score 0):

Camus was a writer and one of the calls of writers, at least as he understood it, was to rouse people to action. A writer, in the old-fashioned European sense, is not merely a man or woman who writes, but someone who thinks, and thinks along with others, because thinking is not a solitary activity but a communal one. This is why Plato's works are *dialogues*. It is an illustration of thinking and it takes place not in the solitary mind of a solitary man - but communally, amongst people and in conversation with them.

Now thinking is not an end in itself. According to Aristotle, and before him, Zarathrustha, the end of thought is action. And not any old action but that which leads to a flourishing life. And hence, a more flourishing world. And as the world is not only full of much good, but also of many evils, it falls on those who have the vision to look to call it out.

What I have called vision here is what Camus calls 'imagination'. Much of what is evil in the world is mundane, the 'banality of evil' as Arendt calls it. To see it as evil and not merely the mundane, everyday feature of the world takes imagination. I am not talking here of the imagination here as certain artists have eulogised it almost to the pointbof absurdity or how today the modern commercial world are selling it back to us as the epitome of cool but as the free possession of every thinking and alive being. Having an imagination is pretty much the same as having a mind.

This is why Camus says 'when the imagination sleeps', he is not talking about a few artists or writers, but everyone. He is talking about the indifference of the world to moral outrages. Except that he did not use the word 'indifferent'. This is because this term is purposefully indifferent. Camus is an optimist and because he is an optimist he believes this is not because of the indifference of the world but because, in a sense, they are asleep. And he one of those who is called to shake them up and wake them up to the injustices in the world ... the 'obscene' injustices hidden behind a smooth and polite and nice 'verbal cloak'.